# ssh login access works fine... Cannot login from GUI Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop installation on an Intel Nuc (bare metal) in my closet. I originally installed Desktop version and have all this year been using it at command line (ssh in from my Mac Book Pro) I do use the password option for ssh. it is a webserver and is still serving the web.

Today I took the Intel Nuc out of my server closet, connected a monitor, mouse and keyboard and saw the GUI for the first time in ages.

It showed me the Purple Screen with the Cat in background I saw my name I tried to login using the same password I have been ssh in for all this year... and now. ssh still works but it wont recognize my password when i type in from GUI. I am thoroughly confused and honestly I do not know what to do. What are my next steps to accessing the Desktop?

FYI: I can see that the keyboard is working.

FYI: I saw something new as I booted onto the the system. A 'Kubuntu' startup passed by before the GUI showed up.

Kind Regards,
Mark

Comment: When you type your password into the GUI and accept it, does it tell you the password is wrong, or does the login box go away and then come back?  Or, to put it another way, does it behave the same way if you intentionally type your password wrong?

Comment: 1) It stays there and stays ready for more characters. It says 'Failed to start session'

Comment: 2) If I type wrong password intentionally I get different message. 'Invalid Password' Try again

Comment: You are actually successfully logging in, and then your graphical session fails to start, either due to problems with config files in your account, or because there is something broken in the graphical at the system level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!. I ssh'd in and ran `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`. It all still works. Why was it so difficult? Is it a bug?

Comment: I edited this thing... But I'm yet to really understand your answer.

Comment: Is the keyboard you are using now the same keyboard you used when installing the system? The keyboard layout may be different. Depending on the characters you are using in your password that might be a problem.

Comment: @Thunderbird. 1) I have no idea why you would bother editing a 'solved' problem? 2) I have no idea why anyone would deduct points for a 'solved' solution. It seems we have other incentives or agendas than just solving ubuntu problems. smh. The Desktop somehow needed re-installing.

Comment: Very likley at some point you uninstalled some critical software needed to make the GUI work.  Installing ubuntu-desktop at least gets the core packages reinstalled.

Answer (score 0):

I really cannot know what is your problem but I can figure out that your problem is regarding the gui, I believe your gui is not working correctly or some other thing,

So first of all while you are on your login screen press ctrl + alt + f5 and enter a text only terminal

There login and then fire the below commands

So first of all delete all the desktop environments from your computer like

```
sudo apt purge gnome*
```

This deletes the default gui

```
sudo apt install tasksel
```

This downloads a gui downloading tool

Then download a new gui -

```
sudo tasksel install ubuntu-desktop
```

### Now probably your gui problem is solved now you can enable ssh again if you want.

Comment: This is the correct analysis. I had already solved it - see below. I like your answer it is more comprehensive. in the ssh connection i was able to issue sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop and that was all i needed. But Thanks. I have no idea how the moderator got so cross here that they deducted points

Comment: Done. And thank you for being a pleasant and helpful Ubuntarian!

Comment: Purging all of gnome is almost certainly overkill and is likely to leave lasting damage on the system of missing packages that installing ubuntu-desktop might not pick up.